# Laravel - Somar data a partir de data salva no banco de dados

Tags: php, laravel

Boa tarde Pessoal,

Estou utilizando o Laravel, e gostaria de criar um metodo com um calculo, que partir de uma data salva no banco "dataSinistro" (que eu mesmo vou inserir em um cadastro) ele busque outro campo no banco "dias" e some esses dias em um novo item na tabela "dataPrescricao".

Gostaria de utilizar o Carbon para isso, mas não estou encontrando a funcionalidade do Carbon que busque a informação a partir do Banco e não estou conseguindo criar algo que funcione nessa situação.

Comment: Confesso que fiquei um pouco confuso, mas coloca o código que você já tem, assim a gente pode entender melhor sua dúvida.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pelo que entendi, você quer somar x dias a uma data do banco

```php
$dataPrescricao = Carbon::createFromFormat("!Y-m-d", $dataSinistro) // Cria uma instância do Carbon com a data do banco
    ->addDays($dias); // Adiciona x dias à data (executa ->modify("+$dias day"))
```